# Equality of stalks implies equality on a neighborhood

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme, $Z$ be a closed subscheme of $X$ and $z$ be a point of $Z$. In the following notes : http://web.mit.edu/~holden1/www/coursework/math/18.787/main.pdf, page 43, claim 6.3 I believe that it is said that to show that $z$ is contained in a open subset of $X$ contained in $Z$ it is enough to show that $\mathscr{O}_{X,z} \cong \mathscr{O}_{Z,z}$.

Is that true and if so why ? Or maybe did I not understand the notes correctly ? In that case what does he mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal I$ be the quasi-coherent ideal sheaf cutting out $Z$, so that
we have a s.e.s. $$0 \to \mathcal I \to \mathcal O_X \to \mathcal O_Z \to 0,$$
and hence a s.e.s of stalks
$$0 \to \mathcal I_x \to \mathcal O_{X,x} \to \mathcal O_{Z,x} \to 0$$
for all points $x \in X$.

To say that $x \in Z$ is to say that $\mathcal O_{Z,z} \neq 0$, or that
$\mathcal I_z$ is a proper ideal in $\mathcal O_{X,z}$.

An open subset $U$ of $X$ is contained in $Z$ *as an open subscheme*
(i.e. the underlying set of $U$ is contained in the underlying set of $Z$, *and* the scheme structure on $U$ is the one induced by regarding it as an open
subscheme of $Z$) iff $\mathcal I_{| U} = 0.$ (Thanks to Alex Youcis for pointing out this subtlety in a comment below.)

So we are given that the stalk $\mathcal I_z = 0$, and we want to conclude
that there is a n.n. $U$ of $z$ such that $\mathcal I_{| U } = 0$.

Suppose that $\mathcal I$ is locally f.g., i.e. that each point (in particular $z$) has a n.h. $V$  so that over $V$ we may find a surjection $\mathcal O_V^n \to \mathcal I_{| V}$, for some $n$.

Then our assumption is that the stalk of this morphism at $z$ is zero, and then 
we may shrink $V$ to some n.n. $U$ of $z$ so that this morphism becomes zero.  (This is where we use the f.g. of $\mathcal I_{| V}$: each generator vanishes in the stalk at $z$, and hence in some n.h. of $z$; since there are only finitely many generators, we may intersect these n.h. to find a n.n. that kills all the generators, and hence s.t. $\mathcal I$ restricts to $0$.)

---

Conclusion: If $\mathcal I$ is loc. f.g. (e.g. if $X$ is locally Notherian),
then the statement is true.

---

It need not be true in general.  E.g. if $$A = k[x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,\ldots, x_n,y_n, \ldots]/(x_1y_1,x_2 y_2,\ldots, x_n y_n, \ldots),$$
and $I = (x_1 , x_2,\ldots, x_n, \ldots),$ which is a prime ideal in $A$,
and $z$ is the point of Spec $A$ corresponding to $I$, and $\mathcal I$ is the associated ideal sheaf (so $Z$ is just the closure of $z$), then $\mathcal I_z = 0$, but $Z$ contains no open n.h. of $z$ in $X$.

You can see the picture here pretty easily: Spec $A$ is a product of infinitely many copies of two lines crossing (i.e. $xy = 0$), and $Z$ is the product of infinitely many copies of one of the two lines (i.e. $x = 0$).

If there were only finitely many (say $n$) copies, then $Z$ would be one of the $2^n$ irred. components of $X$, and would contain a non-empty open subset of $X$ (which would then be the desired n.h. of its generic point $z$); e.g. take a product of $n$ copies of the punctured lines $x = 0, y \neq 0$.

But this breaks down when we take the infinite product (basically b/c an infinite product of non-empty proper opens is not open in an infinite product).

Comment: This is an amazing answer, thank you so much !

Comment: Dear Chet, You're welcome.  (By the way, I looked at the notes, and it looked this was happening within the proof of the rigidity lemma, as stated on p.40 at the start of Lecture 6, and it looks like that lemma has a locally Noeth. hypothesis, which is probably then in force for the rest of the arguments).  Cheers,

Comment: Matt, why is it true that if $U\subseteq Z$ then $\mathcal{I}\mid_U= 0$ if $X$ isn't reduced? What if one takes the reduced subscheme of a non-reduced affine scheme?

Comment: Also, it may be worth noting that what you proved is often times referred to as "Geometric Nakayama's Lemma" :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Dear Alex, Good point!  What I meant was that $U$ is an *open subscheme* of $Z$, i.e. has is an open subset of $Z$ whose scheme structure is induced by that of $Z$.  I'll make an edit to this effect.  Cheers,